# Основа CSS

Tags: html, css

Предположим у меня есть, много дивов с разной позицией, но например с одинаковыми тенями
Вопрос: Для этого, мне надо написать так

```
 <div id="one" class="some"></div>
 <div id="two" class="some"></div>
 <div id="three" class="some"></div>

 .some{
 box-shadow:..
 }
 #one{
 left: 20px;
 }
 #two{
 left: 70px;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ: да.
Общие свойства в класс, индивидуальные по ИД. Но можно и в отдельные классы засунуть.

Comment: +1 ставлю, всё чётко, но не надо рассовывать по отдельным классам, всё же это для общих свойств.

Comment: Согласен, просто в вопросе уже был на столько правильный ответ, что в ответ оставалось написать только ДА.

Comment: ))) да это не для нас ))) отличный ответ ))